# Create a library accessible from csi

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Let's say I have a library foo in `foo.scm` like so:

```
(module foo (bar)
  (import scheme)

  (define (bar arg)
    (+ 5 arg)))
```

And I have a program `program.scm`:

```
(use foo)

(display (bar 2))
```

Now, I compile foo and generate the import library using `csc -J -library foo.scm`, and then compile program with `csc program.scm`. Running program displays "7", as expected and everything is dandy. However, I want to load program interactively in the interpreter (csi), but now for some reason each call to a function in foo has to be prefixed with `foo#`, i.e. in the interpreter `(foo#bar 2)` works, but `(bar 2)` doesn't even though it works when used in a source file.

Why is this? Not only is this slightly annoying, I'm also afraid that I may have a misunderstanding of how the module system works in Chicken, so any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "load the program into the interpreter", but usually `(use foo)` should load and import the library, so performing `(load "program.scm")` should do just that, and all the things exported by `foo` should be available at toplevel.

It sounds like you somehow ended up with a situation where the library has been loaded into the running system, but hasn't been imported for use at toplevel.  Just typing `(use foo)` (or even `(import foo)`) at the REPL should fix this problem.

CHICKEN's module system has been designed to allow for separate compilation, which makes cross-compilation possible.  To make this work, the import library and actual implementation have been separated, but this complicates things a little, as you've discovered. This is needed because the import library may define macros that are needed at compile-time, so it needs to run on the cross-compiling host, whereas the library itself will need to be available in the cross-compilation target's architecture.  We're discussing on how to simplify this for CHICKEN 5, as this is something that confuses many beginners (and sometimes advanced users, too).